# How to detect if image is panned to edge while zoomed in with Flutter InteractiveView?

Tags: flutter

I have an image from file as the child of an InteractiveView. The InteractiveView is itself the child of a PageView. Because of the page controller, I had to disable paging while an image is zoomed in on so that the user can pan the image without it going to the next page.

However, when the image is zoomed in on and panned all the way to the left or right, I want the paging to be enabled again. How can I do this?

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PhotoViewer extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> photoPaths;
  final int startIndex;

  const PhotoViewer({
    super.key,
    required this.photoPaths,
    this.startIndex = 0
  });

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _PhotoViewerState();
}

class _PhotoViewerState extends State<PhotoViewer> {
  late PageController _pageController;
  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;
  bool _pagingEnabled = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedPageIndex = widget.startIndex;
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _selectedPageIndex);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
  }

  void _pageChanged(int index) {
    if (_selectedPageIndex != index) {
      _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
      setState(() {
        _selectedPageIndex = index;
      });
    }
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
  }

  void _onScaleChanged(double scale) {
    setState(() {
      _pagingEnabled = scale <= 1.0;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Trip Photos"), backgroundColor: Colors.black, foregroundColor: Colors.white,),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: PageView(
          physics: _pagingEnabled ? const PageScrollPhysics() : const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          controller: _pageController,
          onPageChanged: _pageChanged,
          children: widget.photoPaths.map((path) => _InteractiveImage(path, _onScaleChanged)).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _InteractiveImage extends StatefulWidget {
  String imgPath;
  Function(double) onScaleChanged;

  _InteractiveImage(this.imgPath, this.onScaleChanged);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _InteractiveImageState();
}

class _InteractiveImageState extends State<_InteractiveImage> {
  late TransformationController _transformationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _transformationController = TransformationController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _transformationController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InteractiveViewer(
      onInteractionEnd: (ScaleEndDetails? details) {
        double scale = _transformationController.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis();
        widget.onScaleChanged(scale);
      },
      transformationController: _transformationController,
      child: Image.file(
          File(widget.imgPath
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```